# Console input, output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am using WebStorm IDE 30 days trial version. While taking input in console I use `readline().split(" ")` method and `print()` method to write output but it's not working.

The following error is given:

Code:

```
var inp = readline().split(' ');
print(inp);
```

Error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var inp = readline();
                                                                    ^

ReferenceError: readline is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Work\J\JS.js:1:73)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Comment: Webstorm is using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to evaluate the script, and that only defines [a few, specific globals](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/globals.html). Everything else from its API must be required – `var readline = require('readline');` ([example use](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/readline.html#readline_readline)). Also, there isn't a `print()` function, but you can use [`console.log()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example below. 
Say you want to create a JavaScript function that adds two numbers and prints out the output to the console in Webstorm.

```
function add(a,b){
return a+b;}

Console.log(add(5,6));
```